# Create multiple posts or update a single post when receiving periodically updated information for an event

Tags: seo, post

For a big horse race in a few months time we receive a log of runners, this log is updated a few times before the race.

Is it better to create a new post for each time we receive the updated log or is it better to have one post which we update a few times.

I am a bit confused because:

A - By creating a new post each time we receive the updated log I feel like I am creating duplicate keywords as it all relates to the same event.

B - By updating the same post with new log details I am changing the words on the page and messing with the original content that has been indexed.

Any advice would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach should be 'what makes sense' for your users. Adding additionally pages purely to satisfy Google and search engines alike is experience suicide. Don't be scared to update pages regardless of keyword ratio, Google and Bing have come along way since they first launched and keyword stuffing is really a thing of the past. Nowadays you keywords will just reach a threshold and thereafter they just don't count to further contributions of the page rankings.

Again, forget the SEO and search engines and do what's best for your audience, experience trumps everything.